# Ошибка, при попытке получения picture url через Flickr API

Tags: c#

[image]

VS 2015, когда я пытаюсь получить url картинки через Flickr API, вылетает вот такое исключение.
 В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: This is ruSO. Translate your question to russian language or redirect to link -->> http://www.stackoverflow.com

Comment: You have to use HTTPS.

Comment: Апи фликкера работают и по http, возможно просто фото заблокировано пользователем.